# .NET Portable Subset missing after Xamarin Studio upgrade - Portable Class Library

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library

Just updated to Xamarin Studio 5 (build 878) but when I create a solution with a PCL project it shows its missing Profile78

Comment: You would be better off asking this on Xamarin's support forums  - forums.xamarin.com

Answer (score 1):

The steps to make PCL work in Visual Studio. Make sure you install in same order.

1. Download and install .NET framework 4.5.1
2. Download and install Mono
3. MDK Download and install PortableLibraryTools2
4. Download and install Microsoft .NET Portable Library Reference Assemblies 4.6
5. Extract files into the PCL reference assemblies directory C:\Program
   Files(x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable
6. Download and install/reinstall Xamarin for Windows

For More info check below blog:
http://xamarinandroid.blogspot.in/2014/06/portable-class-librarypcl-setup-for.html